# how to check for header value using axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am making a get call that will return different values based on the req headers. like an if else. The header has the variable I am looking for but my code does not recognize it. I am new to this. please help.

```
exports.getSession = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.headers.authToken) {
            let authtoken = req.headers('authToken');
            let response = await sessionManager.getSession(authToken);
            res.status(200).json(response.data);
        } else if (req.headers.api_key) {.
            let vegatoken = reqheaders('api_key');
            res.status(200).json(vegatoken);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, have you got an error on your console? if yes can you add it in your question please?

Comment: @vert3x no error message just a warning:
(node:32480) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Comment: can you try req.getHeader('authToken');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it `getSession` is an express-middleware. You can access the headers on the express `req`-object using `req.get(..)/req.header(..)` as described in the documentation http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get

So you could do the following:

```
exports.getSession = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const authTokenHeader = req.header('authToken');
        const apiKeyHeader = req.header('api_key');
        if (authTokenHeader) {
            let response = await sessionManager.getSession(authTokenHeader);
            res.status(200).json(response.data);
        } else if (apiKeyHeader) {
            res.status(200).json(apiKeyHeader);
        }
    } catch(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I can see the header values when I put debug points but it does not associate the value to the const authTokenHeader and also req.header('authToken') shows undefined but I can see it in req.header

Comment: Please `console.log(req.headers)` and post the output here

Comment: for some reason when I was running it in debug mode it did not proceed and there were no console.logs generated but passed in normal run and I got the values. Thanks for the help. really appreciate it.